# How to enforce usage of gradlew over gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

If I have gradle installed on my system and project `foo` that uses the gradle wrapper I have found that I can invoke the the build using `gradle` command or the `gradlew` wrapper.

Suppose that the gradle installed on a system was version 2.2.1 and the gradle wrapper was setup to use gradle version 1.9 what happens if I invoke the system `gradle` will the build run using gradle 2.2.1 or the 1.9 that was specified by the wrapper? How does gradle handle conflicts between the version installed on the system and the one specified by the wrapper? Is there a way to get the build to fail if it is invoked using `gradle` rather than `gradlew` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to enforce `gradlew` over `gradle`. A common solution is to tell/document that everybody should use `gradlew`, and that nobody should install Gradle manually. From my experience this works well (why install something if you don't need to). Power users who need/want a local Gradle installation will typically figure out quickly if they got this wrong.

Comment: are there any special environment vars that or jvm system properties that are only present when the `gradlew` is invoked which `build.gradle` can check for and then exit the jvm and print an error message if they are not there?

Comment: You'd have to check the script, but keep in mind that it might change over time. Alternatively you could customize the script, say by setting your own env var.

Comment: Maybe the gradle team can add `-DinvokedFromGradlew=true` to the generated wrapper scripts and then it would be easy to do this check and fail the build. I think it is worth it to enforce using `gradlew` and it's one less thing that can go wrong due to human error.

Comment: One option is to modify the wrapper scripts to specify such a system property as a JVM argument.